# RMagick - Which rmagick method should i use to optimize Big Images to reduce image load time?

Tags: optimization, image-processing, rmagick

I Have a full size slider with big images
for example: `1885x1440`
these are photos and i need to optimize them with `RMagick` but keep the quality and image size (`1885x1440`)

I think it should be one of this methods http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/image3.html

I don't quite know how should i proceed to optimize this images so they can load faster and still look amazing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try [this](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/comtasks.html#compressing).

Note that some formats, like PNG, don't use compression by default. You can check the supported/default compression types for each format [here](http://www.imagemagick.org/RMagick/doc/info.html#compression). So for PNGs you could try something like:

```
img.write("myimage.png") {
  self.compression = Magick::ZipCompression
  self.quality = 50
}
```